# change platform win32 to x64 of unmanaged vc++ dll

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, 64-bit

I have a dll in vc++ (unmanaged) at win32 platform.Now I want to convert it into X64 plateform.How it is possible.Before win32 the dll was at pocket PC 2003(ARMV4) platform.I converted it into win32.
I tried it to change from configuration manager but it not done.

Comment: no vs2008 proffesional edition

Comment: The 64-bit compilers are not installed by default.  Re-run VS2008 setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeed need to add a new (x64) configuration to the solution platform with the configuration manager.

Additionally you change the machine type in the Linker/Advanced settings.

Comment: :But my dll contain 8 module(static library).so we have to change platform to all the module one by one or only master project.

Comment: Verify that "Create new prjects platforms" is checked when adding 64 bit solution platform. In this case all projects in your solution get the x64 addition.